# Echo divs inside Foreach loop

Tags: php, web, foreach

Im developing a web page which contains a posting section.
I have an `Array` called `$posts` which contains `Title`, `body`, `date`, and `name` of the image from the post (rows come from a data base). 
This array is filled with all postings in the page, and when I use a foreach I want to echo these variables inside this block of code when running a foreache:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
   <img class="img-responsive img-border img-full" src="../img/NAME.jpg" alt="">
     <h2>TITLE
        <br>
        <small>DATE</small>
          </h2>
          <p>BODY</p>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Button</a>
           <hr>
</div>
```

This is the structure of the array:

```
$post= [
    "title",
    "date",
    "body",
    "name"
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use below code in foreach condition

```
<?php foreach($post as $po){ ?>
 <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
   <img class="img-responsive img-border img-full" src="<?php echo $po['name'];?>" alt="">
   <h2><?php echo $po['title'];?>
        <br>
        <small><?php echo $po['date'];?></small>
   </h2>
   <p><?php echo $po['body'];?></p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Button</a>
   <hr>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```